# Setting the minDate of a second datepicker depending on the first datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have scoured SO for the solution and I would say I have looked at all of the questions and anwsers but I don't think that actiually possible.

I have tryed various solutions but none of them seem to work...

I'm sure it's an easy fix, but I can't get it to work. Any help would be most appriciated.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#arrivalDate").datepicker({
        minDate: 'dateToday',
        onSelect: function (date) {
            $("#departureDate").datepicker({
                minDate: date
            });
        }
    });
    $("#departureDate").datepicker();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, the only issue is with how you attempt to set the `minDate` - you need to use `option`, like this:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#arrivalDate").datepicker({
    minDate: 'dateToday',
    onSelect: function(date) {
      $("#departureDate").datepicker('option', 'minDate', date);
    }
  });
  
  $("#departureDate").datepicker();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<p>Arrival: <input type="text" id="arrivalDate" /></p>
<p>Departure: <input type="text" id="departureDate" /></p>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help